# What's com.superthomaslab.rootessentials?

Tags: root-access

[image: screenshot]

What is `com.superthomaslab.rootessentials`? Having root access, no icons no name, just a package name. Please note that [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.superthomaslab.rootessentials) isn't installed on my devvice

Comment: You have lucky patcher ... Most luck patchers are malware now, unless it's actually from the original developer, i would guess it's something to do with a trojan ... just a guess.... Have you checked if it's a widget or if it can be launched from the settings menu ?

Comment: The app linked is developed by one of our community with same name. @SuperThomaslab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That app was installed at one point and granted root, then later uninstalled which is why the package name is showing up in SuperSU with no icon instead of the application name. You can test this with any app you've granted root access to. Uninstall it and the same thing will happen.